# JADE: pausing a behavior and resume execution from last point

Tags: java, agents-jade

I m working on JADE Java Agent Dev' Platform, and i m facing a problem of receiving messages while waiting for specific ones.

I have an Agent with two behaviors
First behavior is does receive messages from other Agents.
Second implements agent logic. which is as follow

```
    action1 ...
    send message to an agent
    wait for reply // this is blocking
    action2 ...
```

The wait for reply part does wait for result from target agent which is satisfied in no other agents interfere sending message to this Agent.

The problem is when this Agent is waiting for a reply ( putting its ReceiverBehavior ) on hold due to action method policies.
If it receives the reply, everything is fine. However if meanwhile a message was sent to this agent, the data received is wrong and action2 part is no longer valid. In matter of fact, this interference of other agent's messages should be received by the ReceiverBehavior.

I was thinking of putting the behavior onhold after sending the a message. As a consequence terminate the "action" method to let the ReceiverBehavior receiving new messages, When the concerned message is received, it will notify theh behavior and let it resume. But, it should resume execution from action2.

I hope i was clear enough explaining the problem.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood you right, you should use MessageTemplate to receive suitable responces.

```
MessageTemplate mt = ...
ACLMessage aclMessage = myAgent.receive(mt);
if(aclMessage == null){
   block(TIMEOUT);
} else {
  ...
}
```